# app causes crash in Leaks tool

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks, crash, instruments

My app closes automatically after some time.There is no crash log in the device also.After some googling I guessed that will be a memory leaks issue.But the Leaks in the Instruments crashes on targeting my app.

Can anyone suggest me what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Try looking at other tools, especially the allocations one.  Also, you may want to reinstall the sdk.  It's very strange that the tool should crash like that.

Comment: @WolfLink I have tried allocations and it gave me an idea where might be the leaks....Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @WolfLink If you add the comment as an answer , I will accept it as the correct one. I dont know whether I can accept a comment as the answer.

Comment: Thanks!  And no, you cannot accept a comment, but you will be able to upvote them when you have higher reputation, as I have demonstrated on yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at other tools, especially the allocations one. Also, you may want to reinstall the sdk. It's very strange that the tool should crash like that.